# About travelling to Croatia with Schengen visa in invalid passport

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, croatia

I am an Indian national with a France Schengen visa valid until 2021. I know that a Croatia visa is not required if I have a multiple-entry Schengen visa. However, my old passport is full and I got a new passport. But I am not sure whether I can use the Schengen visa in the old passport together with my new passport to travel to Croatia. Could you please help me with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Most countries allow this.

Answer (score 4):

I asked the police by email and they said that I can use Schengen visa in my old passport together with my new passport to enter Croatia.

Comment: Perfect, print out their E-Mail if you fly directly to Croatia to show at airport check-in if needed

Comment: TIP: also E-Mail IATA, who operate the Airline document verification database Timatic, and tell them about this, **attaching the E-Mail as evidence**, so it can be added to facilitate check-in for future travellers.

Answer (score 2):

Timatic, the database used by airport check-in staff, frequently outlines whether valid visas in expired passports (together with a new passport) are accepted by a given country, but there is no information on Croatia.

As such, without further information, you'will probably be denied boarding on a flight to Croatia.

For Slovenia and Hungary (Schengen countries), however:

> Valid visas in full, invalidated travel documents are
>     accepted if accompanied by a new travel document

So you could fly to one of those and catch the train or bus to Croatia from there. Croatian police at these borders is *extremely* relaxed towards EU/EFTA citizens, and fairly relaxed to others as well.

If you need to be 100% sure about Croatia, e-mail the police at pitanja@mup.hr

Start the message by writing "To the border police department" and ask if valid Schengen visas in expired passports can be used together with a new passport.

They should give you a reply, although most likely in Croatian (Google Translate it in this case)

Comment: I asked the police by email and they said that I can use Schengen visa in my old passport together with my new passport to enter Croatia.